# how to open configure portable Wi-Fi hotspot setting by onclick?

Tags: android, settings, onclicklistener, buttonclick

how to open the following directory:settings/wireless and networks/Tethering and portable hotspot/portable Wi-Fi hotspot settings/configure portable Wi-Fi hotspot/  on button click?
i want to achieve this using onClick method not id method.
below is my code

```
<RadioButton
        android:onClick="togglewifi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Toggle Wifi" />


public void togglewifi(View view) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(             );
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

This code works for 4.2.2

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity( intent);
```

Comment: I need to intent go to hotspot setting. So i can change hotspot password

Comment: Works on 7.1.1, saved my life

Comment: This opens the Tethering screen. Is there another way to open the WiFi Hotspot screen only? I know it's possible because SHAREit does that.

Comment: This is also works for me? Is it possible to on hotspot instead of getting hotspot setting?

Answer (score 6):

In case any one lands here like me, on Android 8, I used this to open up the setup Hotspot page itself.

```
public static final String SETTINGS_PACKAGE = "com.android.settings";
public static final String HOTSPOT_SETTINGS_CLASS = "com.android.settings.Settings$TetherWifiSettingsActivity";

private void launchHotspotSettings(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(SETTINGS_PACKAGE, HOTSPOT_SETTINGS_CLASS);
    intent.setComponent(componentName);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Works on my device.
Let me know if it works on yours.
After a bit of research I realized that this class changes per device brand.
Eg. For Samsung, use

```
public static final String HOTSPOT_SETTINGS_CLASS = "com.android.settings.Settings$WifiApSettingsActivity";
```

By the way @Drew answer still works on Android 8.

Comment: Hi dosky, how did you get that information? I have an example working on Samsung but i need it also for Sony, Huawei, etc... How do i find the "path" of those custom activities on those phones?
Thanks!

Comment: Goodday. I basically checked the logs.
When you inspect the logs, every new page tells you what activity was opened.

I can see mine under Info logs and most times it comes with the tag **ActivityManager** or you could just search for **Settings** or **com.android.settings.Settings**, then try navigating to the page you want. 
You should see stuff like this.

`09-12 19:19:39.345 805-858/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity: +603ms`

Comment: Let me know if you have issues.
NB: The device has to be connected to the device and in debug mode.

Also, if you can compile the list successfully, please help me with a Gist url for it. I don't have much devices around me.

Comment: Hi Doski, I've tried what you say but I cannot see the information completly, trying on a Samsung S9 y can only see this:
I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.SubSettings: +430ms
Is there any option that I have to activate to see this "Subsettings" more explicit?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try navigating to the hotspot setup activity itself?
You need to navigate to the activity you want, then check what was logged.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I did. From homescreen, go to settings, etc.... all this connected via usb, usb debug enabled and logging via android studio.
Am i missing something?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the silence.
I will check another device and get back to you.

Comment: This crashes for me.

Answer (score 2):

Activate Tethering in Java:

```
private void activeTethering(){
    Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
    tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");

    startActivity(tetherSettings);
}
```

and in Kotlin:

```
private fun activeTethering(){
    val tetherSettings = new Intent().apply {
        setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings")
    }

    startActivity(tetherSettings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you all your devices including SAMSUNGS.

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            final ComponentName componentName;
            componentName    =new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
            intent.setComponent(componentName);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```

Kotlin:

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    val cn = ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings")
    intent.component = cn
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score -2):

use "button" instead of "RadioButton"

in layout try this:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="togglewifi" />
```

in activity.java try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void togglewifi(View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));


}
}
```

Comment: jeetu, i don't want to open wifi settings, i want to open "configure portable Wi-Fi hotspot".