# How to take users to Android Tethering menu from Chrome Android browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I'm trying to build a web link that would open (from Chrome) to Android Tethering & portable hotspot menu.

Chrome on Android supports passing intents from URLs:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

However, there doesn't seem to be a known standard intent that would invoke that menu (Android common intents: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html).

Is there a way to make that work, maybe using explicit intents? If so, how should the syntax of "component" look like in the URL?
    #Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;package=com.android.settings;component=what_should_go_here;end

The closest I could find from about intents for Tethering menu: [how to open configure portable Wi-Fi hotspot setting by onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719905/how-to-open-configure-portable-wi-fi-hotspot-setting-by-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. Here is how the intent should be formatted:

```
#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;component=com.android.settings/.TetherSettings;end
```